# %d inside variable filename in C

Tags: c

Making a program that logs data. I want it to start a new file with an incremented integer every time it reaches a set limit of file space (in bytes).

Everything works fine until I use:

```
file_name = ("Data%d.bin",fileIncrement);
```

Instead of:

```
file_name = "Data.bin";
```

When I replace the above, the software no longer writes to a file.

Here is the function in question:

```
    char *file_name;
    static int fileSize = 0;  //bytes
    static int fileIncrement = 1;

    //Set file name
    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        file_name = ("Data%d.bin",fileIncrement);
        ++fileIncrement;
    }

    fileSize += size;

    if (fileSize >= 1024)
    {
        fileSize = 0;
    }

    // Write to file system
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I initially tried with a time stamp, but that didn't work and brought it back to basics.

Comment: Edit you question to add more information. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: That's why it's not a good idea to program by randomly guessing syntax. Rather, you need to learn programming systematically and build only on things that you have fully understood in isolation before combining them into larger components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file path for `fopen`, `open` etc... is a string. You can build that string, e.g. using [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), like e.g.

```
char filepath[256];
snprintf (filepath, sizeof(filepath), "Data%d.bin", fileIncrement);
FILE * fil = fopen(filepath, "w");
if (!fil) { perror(filepath); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

**Read the documentation** of [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) -and *of every function you are using*-; you'll need to add some more `#include` directives.

Avoid using  `sprintf` (but use `snprintf`) because you should be scared of [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and other [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

<sup>You might even test the result of `snprintf` to be sure it is succeeding and fits in `filepath`.</sup>

At compilation time, *enable debugging information and all warnings* (i.e. compile with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 7):

Many people seem to think that just because you can do

```
printf("%d", 4711);
```

to print an integer, you should be able to use `("%d", 4711)` *anywhere* to format an integer into a string.

This is *not true*, and not how C works. In C, *functions* do this kind of work, and the function here is of course `printf()`, which means "print, formatted".

You can use another function to do the formatting without the printing, like `snprintf()`:

```
char buf[32];

snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "Data%d.bin", fileIncrement);
```

Then pass `buf` to the function doing the opening, i.e. `fopen(buf, "rb")` or whatever.